# Django proxy model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

```
class DeviceType(models.Model):
    device_type = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.device_type

class Device(models.Model):
    device_type         = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType,to_field='device_type')
    serial_number       = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    in_use_by           = models.ForeignKey(User,to_field='username')
    brand               = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="-", null=False)
    model               = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="-", null=False)
    type_number         = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    mac_address         = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
```

I want to make a django form that would have a drop-down as follows: (Below is the general pattern of the data present in drop-down menu):

devicetype-serialnumber-model-brand

e.g: Laptop-abcd1234-T45k-QWER

How can I achieve this using Django proxy model?

Comment: What does this have to do with proxy models? If you want to make a form, make a form.

Comment: Then, how do I combine the data and display it as a form drop down menu?  @DanielRoseman

Comment: See [the docs for ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield); either define the `__str__` method on the model, or use a custom subclass of ModelChoiceField that defines `label_from_instance`.